# Erro ao tentar instalar o nodemon

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, nodemon

Estou tentando instalar o nodemon pelo visual studio code usando o "npm install --save -g nodemon", mas aparece esse erro e não instala.

[image]

Comment: Tente sempre colocar o código por texto, e não uma imagem dele.

Comment: Poderia tentar instalar sem o argumento (flag) `"-g"` e tentar novamente?

Comment: já fiz isso. não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Limpa o cache com o comando: `npm cache clean --force` 
Em seguida roda o comando: `npm i nodemon` ou: `npm install -g nodemon`